# Erro para obter versão do Windows 10 com delphi

Tags: delphi

Estou tentando obter a versão do Windows 10 em meu sistema, mas o máximo que ele exibe é o Windows 8. Nem 8.1 ele exibe.
Não consegui achar o erro.

```
// Função Sistema Operacional
function WinVersion: string;
var
  VersionInfo: TOSVersionInfo;
begin
  VersionInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize:=SizeOf(VersionInfo);
  GetVersionEx(VersionInfo);
  Result:='';
  with VersionInfo do
  begin
    case dwPlatformId of
      1:
        case dwMinorVersion of
          0:  Result:='Microsoft Windows 95';
          10: Result:='Microsoft Windows 98';
          90: Result:='Microsoft Windows Me';
        end;
      2:
    case dwMajorVersion of
      5:
        case dwMinorVersion of
          0:
            Result := 'Microsoft Windows 2000';
          1:
            Result := 'Microsoft Windows XP';
          2:
            Result := 'Microsoft Windows Server 2003';
        end;
      6:
        case dwMinorVersion of
          0:
            Result := 'Microsoft Windows Vista';
          1:
            Result := 'Microsoft Windows 7';
          2:
            Result := 'Microsoft Windows 8';
          3:
            Result := 'Microsoft Windows 8.1';
        end;
      10:
        case dwMajorVersion of
          0:
             Result := 'Microsoft Windows 10';
            end;
        end;
    end; 
  end; 
  if (Result='') then
    Result:='Sistema operacional desconhecido.';
end;
// Fim da Função SO
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seu algoritmo esta até correto, o problema é que a Microsoft ao lançar uma nova versão do Windows ela troca dos demais a `MinorVersion`, fazendo com que seu algoritmo fique desatualizado e informando incorretamente a versão!

Executando seu algoritimo, me foi mostrado a versão do Case `dwMajorVersion`  6 e `dwMinorVersion` 3, retornando que meu Windows seria `Windows 8.1`, mas.... Como estou usando `Windows 10 Pro` nos últimos updates (sou Insider) meu *Major* é 6 e meu *Minor* é 3.

A forma mais eficaz de obter essa informação e com 100% de certeza é ler os registros do Windows.

Segue exemplo de como fazer:

Declare nas `uses` do seu projeto `Registry`

```
function frmTeste.ObterVersaoWindows: String;
var
  vNome,
  vVersao,
  vCurrentBuild: String;
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg         := TRegistry.Create; //Criando um Registro na Memória
  Reg.Access  := KEY_READ; //Colocando nosso Registro em modo Leitura
  Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE; //Definindo a Raiz

  //Abrindo a chave desejada
  Reg.OpenKey('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\', true); 

  //Obtendo os Parâmetros desejados
  vNome         := Reg.ReadString('ProductName');
  vVersao       := Reg.ReadString('CurrentVersion');
  vCurrentBuild := Reg.ReadString('CurrentBuild');

  //Montando uma String com a Versão e alguns detalhes
  Result := vNome + ' - ' + vVersao + ' - ' + vCurrentBuild;
end;
```

Para usar basta:

```
ComponenteX.Caption := ObterVersaoWindows;
ComponenteX.Text    := ObterVersaoWindows;
ShowMessage(ObterVersaoWindows);
etc... etc...
```

Ate mais, aguardo seu Feedback!

Comment: Perfeito obrigado!

Comment: Muito bom, testei no WIndows 8, 10 e no server e funcionou, parabens.

Comment: Muito Obrigada, funcionou certinho.